# Cookies Change-If we add(/?) with URL content changes are reflected

Tags: cookies

We have done content changes in site([www.windstream.com](http://www.windstream.com))after changing content in this site and we clear cookies as well. But still changes are not reflected. If we add(/?) with URL content changes are reflected.

Can you please help to sort out this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using Cloudflare caching, and also the Blitz plugin. You'll need to find a way to clear both those caches after making changes. [image]

[image]